# npm could not find module '../lib/npm.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm

I am trying to use nodejs and npm on a CentOS 7 machine. The machine cannot connect to the Internet, so I copy the node-v6.2.1-linux-x64 folder with some lib modules inside to the machine. But the output shows `Error: Cannot find module '../lib/npm.js'`. I wonder if it is the correct way to install nodejs offline or modules. Any helps? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work because the node modules  depend to your operating system.

For example , lets say I have a project with tons of node dependencieses and I ran `npm install`  on my Microsoft machine, when I copy my files and try to run it in  Apple , it wouldn't work.

You have to use  `npm i` seperetly on different machines.

Maybe this link here can help you to get your npm modules without internet . ==>

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1349

Comment: They are both Centos.. almost same environment.

Comment: logically then it should work , but when I tried  windows 10 npm modules directly in a windows 7 machine, it didn"t work for me either